# Sending a variable in json object via python script

Tags: python, json, api, rest, http

I have a UI end point that I am calling through a Python script. I want to pass variable in payload data but somehow Python is not reading it as a variable hence PUT request does not works, I need help in how to send this as a variable. In below code I want to pass tid value as a variable. tid is a json array with value tid = ["defaultd"]. I also tried to make it working by adding square brackets to the variable value.

> 

```
def assign_tenant():            
    token = get_client_token()
    user_id = get_user_id()                        
    tid = get_tenants()                                                
    tid = f'[{tid}]'                                              
    url = mcs_url + "security/users/keycloak/" + user_id
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Accept": "application/json",                                                                              
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }                              
    print('This is tenant id', tid)             
    data = '{"authenticationType":"LOCAL","email":"test@test.com","enabled":"true","firstName":"Super","lastName":"Admin","tenant":["tid"]}'
```

Comment: Please, use this library: 
https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: You should know that Python has [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module than can convert simple objects into proper JSON objects

Comment: @matszwecja I am using these already, but the problem is when I send a PUT request with above data, variable value does not seems to populate:

Comment: response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
this is the request I am using